# How to add new line after user input in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script which takes input from user for password. After the password prompt, what ever command I run in the next line, the output of that command is printed at the password prompt. How to avoid printing the output at password prompt.

code:

```
echo -n "Enter Password:"
read -s password
```

Expected output:

```
Enter Password:
Login successful.
```

Current output:

```
Enter Password:Login successful.
```

Comment: Social enginnering - faking login screen. ;) Just use `read -rsp 'Password:' pass ; echo`

Comment: Thank you, both the answers worked.

Answer (score 4):

`echo` a line after you've read the password:

```
echo -n "Enter Password:"
read -s password
echo
```